# Org export to latex and HTML references

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have been working on a document that I want to export to both HTML and latex; while working on the document I noticed that using latex `\label{}` and `\ref{}` tags works properly for latex export, but these are shown as plain tex in the HTML export.
Similarly if I use Org links for references inside the document (for example a link to an Org header ) these are translated as links in the HTML export, but the latex export only shows a different typografy (`\texttt{}`), but I don't get any hyperlink characteristic.

Is there a way to the same behavior for both exports, either latex directives to translate into html links or Org links as in-file references for the latex export?

For an example of what I'm dealing with please check the following snippet.

```org
#+OPTIONS: H4 num:3 toc:nil \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:nil -_t f:t *:t <:t
#+OPTIONS: TeX:t LaTeX:t skip:nil d:nil todo:t pri:nil tags:not-in-toc
#+OPTIONS: author:t email:nil creator:nil timestamp:nil
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{geometry}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=blue}


* Section name
\label{sec:section_name} (not working properly in html export)
some text
#+LABEL: fig:image
[[img][file:image]]
some reference to figure \ref{fig:image} =link work in latex but not in html=
* other section
reference to [[* Section name][link work in html, but not latex export]],but if I use the reference \nameref{sec:section_name} will not work in html, but it will in latex export
```

PS: I'm aware that I may try to use pandoc, but I have never used it and I don't know if I will get the desired result, and I'd rather not use add additional tools to the toolchain.

Thanks in advance

-- Edit, Added org-mode fragment as example

Comment: Can you give an example of your Org code? The second option you describe should actually do what you want. I.e. for example, `[[Heading title]]` should generate an anchor link in HTML and a reference in LaTeX file. If you want to style the links, you can use `#+LATEX_HEADER: \hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}` and
`#+LATEX_HEADER: \hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}` (and see http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-130003.9 for more options).

Comment: Note that `\nameref{sec:section_name}` is absolutely not stable!  E.g. in the current Org version, labels are translated to something like `sec:orgheading1` by default unless `org-latex-prefer-user-labels` is non-`nil`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A couple of things..

1. The syntax for figure/table labels is `#+NAME:`. You also need to use `#+CAPTION:` if you want to cross-reference them.
2. You do not need to use the `\label` syntax; it's much simpler in org-mode.

   - To reference the section `Section name` (from your example), you use `[[Section name]]`.
   - To reference that figure in your example, you use `[[fig:image]]`.
3. You need to use the `#+LaTeX:` prefix for LaTeX-only code.

#### Working MWE

```org
* Section name
some text
#+CAPTION: Fig Caption
#+NAME: fig:image
[[file:img]]
some reference to figure [[fig:image]] =link will work in both html and latex=
* other section
reference to Section [[Section name]] =link will work in both html and latex=
```

#### Using `CUSTOM_ID` to refer to sections

Thanks to the tip from **@rasmus** in the comments, this is a better way to link to sections as it decouples the section name from the link name.

```org
* Introduction
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: sec:intro
:END:
some text
* Conclusion
This links to Section [[#sec:intro]] and this link will work in both html and latex. 
*It is important to prefix the custom ID with the =#= character.*
```

#### One more way to refer to sections ([double angular brackets](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html))

```org
* Introduction
<<sec:intro>>
some text
* Conclusion
This links to Section [[sec:intro]] and this link will work in both html and latex.
*You do not prefix the link name with the =#= character here.*
```

#### References

1. [Figures in org-mode](http://orgmode.org/manual/Images-and-tables.html)
2. [Internal Links](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html)
3. [Quoting LaTeX](http://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-LaTeX-code.html)

Comment: In addition you can  use `CUSTOM_ID` to refer to headings.  I would recommend this as it makes references to headings orthogonal to the the displayed name.

Comment: @rasmus CUSTOM_ID didn't work for me for latex/pdf exports (labels were auto generated: example `sec:5-1`), but worked fine for html exports.

Comment: you use `custom_id` like `[[#my-custom-id]]`.  To force custom-id to be used as labels you can use `org-latex-prefer-user-labels` in the git ver version of org (it's called something else in 8.2).

Comment: @rasmus Thanks. I'll try that out later today. But `[[my-custom-id]]` (without the #) worked, but only for html exports. May be I just need to set that var.

Comment: **Update** I stand corrected; the links did not work in html export too unless I used the `#` before `my-custom-id`. But with `#`, the link works great in both html and pdf exports. I did not need to set any var. Thanks!

Comment: @rasmus I have updated the solution.

Comment: @KaushalModi
Is this also possible for external links? I've tried it but I couldn't find a solution. 
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63224/the-export-of-external-links-in-org-files-to-pdf-and-html-files