# The export of external links in org files to pdf and html files

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, html, pdf

I have a problem with the export of external links in org files to pdf and html files.

Let's say I have the two org files in the same directory:

`file1.org` =

```
here is the label of file1:  <<label>>
```

and `file2.org` =

```
go to the label of file1: [[file:./file1.org::label]]
```

After exporting: Both links of `file2.html` and `file2.pdf` don't work.

Both variables `org-latex-prefer-user-labels` and `org-html-prefer-user-labels` are `t`. So the labels are constructed with the correct name (also correct format?):

In `file1.html`:

```html
here is the label of file1:  <a id="label"></a>
```

In `file1.tex`:

```tex
here is the label of file1:  \label{label}
```

In `file2.html`:

```html
go to the label of file1: <a href="./file1.html#MissingReference">./file1.html#MissingReference</a>
```

The linked file is here correct (`file1.html`) but the label isn't found.

In `file2.tex`:

```tex
go to the label of file1: \url{./file1.org}
```

The *org* file is linked not the *pdf* file. So  even the linked file is here wrong.

What I've tried is using the `CUSTOM_ID` as label. This works perfectly with the html export but not with the pdf export. And I prefer the <<..>> labels because they are more flexible.

Any Idea to solve the problem? Should I use another link format?
(Org version: 9.4.4)

Comment: Cool question!! Thank you for asking!!

Comment: @Melioratus if you find this question interesting, you can give it a vote to show your thanks ;)

Comment: Upvoted interesting question, done!

Comment: Thanks!  I hope someone can help.